# Is it possible to use Kotlin code in iphone?

Tags: android, iphone, kotlin

Android Studio 3.5.
Write my custom module on Kotlin.
On Android it's work fine.
Nice.

Is it possible to use my module in iPhone? E.g. like library or dependency or smt. else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You would need to make your module available as a "Framework" on iOS (mac/iPad OS).

Here is a tutorial on how to do it.

There could be some features that are limited or may not work but I suppose you'll find out as you work

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/apple-framework.html

Comment: This can work for business logic.  If you need to write UI, or integrate with low level OS operations you'll need to completely port it.